# Edit Datagrid combobox or textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a datagrid and I want the users to be able to edit the values in one of the columns. However depending on the value in another column I either need to have them enter the values in a textbox (other column value = 0) or pick a value from a combobox (other column value > 00) that I will populate from a Dictionary.

How would I do something like this?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code you can show us? There are many ways to do this. You can, for example, bind column 2's content to column 1's content and have a converter in between to decide what control column 2 should have.

Comment: Well I haven't tried anything yet and was searching for tips on how to do something like this. So far I hadn't found anything so maybe I wasn't searching off the correct key words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the TemplateColumn for your DataGrid and define its CellTemplate as below:

```
 <DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentPlaceholder">
                            <ContentControl.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <ComboBox />
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding COLUMNTWOPROPERTY}" Value="0">
                                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding PROPERTYFORTEXTBOX}"/>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </ContentControl.Style>
                        </ContentControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Here COLUMNTWOPROPERTY is the value which decides whether cell should show textbox or combobox.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, had to change ControlTemplate to DataTemplate otherwise it wouldn't compile.